# redirect a logged user to a page in joomla

Tags: php, forms, joomla, redirect

I'm doing a form in more page on joomla.

I'd like to do a thing

The user log-in the site. Complete the first page of the form, after when insert the data e click on a button I will be redirect to another page of the form

I tried this code

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
  $id = $user->get('id');
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
header("Location: http://www.mysite/second-page-form");
exit;
}
```

But it doesn't work

I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to check for the session. You can simply detect if the user is logged in:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$app  = JFactory::getApplication();
if(!$user->guest)
{
    $app->redirect(JRoute::_('URL GOES HERE STARTING WITH index.php'), false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it will set the `location` header of the response to the location of your second page:

```
if($user->id)
{
    header("Location: http://www.mysite/second-page-form");
    exit;
}
```